# Modifying manage.py for development and production

Tags: python, django, deployment, django-manage.py

My project has a `base.py`, a `dev.py` and a `production.py` (pretty self explanatory).

On my PC I only keep the `dev.py` and `base.py` and on the server I only keep `production.py` and `base.py`.

While the WSGI isn't an issue, I do find myself always having to go into `manage.py` after each deployment to change the `os.environ.setdefault()` setting.

I wanted to change this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.dev") #or project.settings.production

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

to this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.dev")
    except:
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.production")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

However this still raises an `ImportError`. Any ideas why? Or do you know a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to control this is using the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in the shells where you want to use `manage.py`.
The default `manage.py` should not have to change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

As for the `ImportError`,
I'm not sure we have enough information to debug it.
But basically you need to make sure that the file is either reachable from the current working directory,
or from a directory on `PYTHONPATH`.
For example, if you run `manage.py` from the project's root,
and `project/settings/dev.py` exists, then the value "project.settings.dev" should work.